# Are magic numbers always bad?

Tags: string, numbers, constants

Is it considered bad practice to hard code strings which are self descriptive and will only ever be used in one place? Do you always replace hard coded strings with constant variables? What about numbers? Are they ever self descriptive enough to not create variables? Can you give an example where a magic number would be appropriate in your opinion?

Comment: The answer to all of these questions are: "it depends", or "it is a matter of opinion".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with hard coding strings that "will only be used in one place" is this: if you need to change the string, you have to go hunting in your code. Take the version number of a program. You might only use it in a dialog box that's called from the "info" menu - but if you hard code it there, then every time you update the version number you have to find the string "somewhere". Having all constant strings in one place makes that much easier.

As for numerical values - there are some cases (for example, in scientific equations) where occasional constants can be hard wired. Typically this is only true for integers (nobody would flinch at the hard coded `2` in `circumference = 2 * pi * radius;`). Other constants would again be better defined in one place - easier to debug and maintain. I prefer defining `pi` just once, for example (my preference: `pi = 2 * asin(1.0);`). Same with `e` (`e = exp(1.0);`).

Think about the person who looks at / uses your code in six months time. Are you making their life easier or harder? What if they move to a different platform? Such questions can help you make the right choices.

Comment: Good examples and things to think about, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  in which language you want to write, because they will all have their own preferred solution, but for instance in C / C++ an `enum` is often the way to go.

Strictly-typed enums of C++11 are even better.